Please make sure that the argument Array at index [0] is available in the CategoryModule context
I am trying to make a nestJs(with GraphQL Code First) Interceptor which modifies the response before sending it to the client. In this interceptor i am trying to replace the field with the appropriate translation of a field in the language specified by the client in the request headers(for e.g. if user asks for "ES" i.e. Spanish, the interceptor replaces the field with the appropriate translation and sends it in response).
Now the problem,
The above logic is working fine except when i am trying to make this interceptor accept an array of the fields i want to replace(for e.g. in some use cases i want to replace "name" field with the translation and sometimes i want to replace "name" and "description" and sometimes other fields too) to make it work with dynamic fields
This is how i call it in CategoryResolver
@Mutation(() => Category)
@UseInterceptors(new LanguageInterceptor(['name']))

This is how the interceptor looks like
@Injectable()
export class LanguageInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
    constructor(
        private readonly fields: string[]
    ) { }

    async intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Promise<Observable<any>> {
        const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context).getContext();
        const languages: string[] = ['EN', 'ES', 'FI']

        let language = ctx.req.headers['language'];

        if (!language || languages.indexOf(language) === -1) {
            ctx.req.headers['language'] = 'EN';
            language = 'EN';
        }

        return next.handle().pipe(
            map(data => {
                for (const field of this.fields) {
                    if (data && data.translations && Array.isArray(data.translations)) {
                        const translation = data.translations.find((t: any) => t.language === language);
                        if (translation) {
                            data[`${field}`] = translation[`${field}`];
                        }
                    }
                }
                return data;
            }),
        );
    }
}

This is how the providers array in categoryModule looks like (the module in which this interceptor is being used)
providers: [
    LanguageInterceptor,
    CategoryResolver,
    CategoryService,
    UploadFileServices,
  ],

The error It gives

Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the LanguageInterceptor (?). Please make sure that the argument Array at index [0] is available in the CategoryModule context.
Potential solutions:
Is CategoryModule a valid NestJS module?
If Array is a provider, is it part of the current CategoryModule?
If Array is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within CategoryModule?
@Module({
imports: [ /* the Module containing Array */ ]
})

errors which says "argument Array at index [0]" are new for me
I dont understand what this error is trying to say like how do i import array in module context
p.s. in LanguageInterceptor constructor, when i declare fields as just string it doesnot give any error but when i declare it as string[] it gives this error. Also type 'any' doesnt work either.
